# Without using useEffect call api in React-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have been working with react-hooks for a while now, and was under impression useEffect is called once there is some changes been made. But in my case when calling api in useEffect, it renders data continuously.

Here is my useEffect code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default function BookFunction() {
    
    const [bookData, setBookData] = useState([])

     useEffect(() => {
         function fetchInfo() {
            axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
                setBookData(data.data)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
         }
         fetchInfo()
     }, [])

    console.log('this is bookdata',bookData) => bookdata is printed in the browser again and again

}
```

when I do console.log(bookData), it renders over and over again in browser.

How can I prevent this, such that it renders only once or twice?

I tried doing without using useEffect as,

```
     function fetchInfo() {
        axios.post(`/api/book/bookDetails`).then((data) => {
            setBookData(data.data)
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            })
     }
     fetchInfo()
```

But it crashed the system.

Is there anyother way such that I can achieve my goal? If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Comment: Where did you put the console.log?

Comment: By the look of your code, `useEffect` should run only once, on mount. However, it's important to know where exactly have you put the `console.log`.

Comment: Why do you declare a function(`fetchInfo`) inside the useEffect and then call it, but not directly execute the content of the `fetchInfo` function?

Comment: I have added complete code . Please have a look.

Comment: @SinanYaman Are you telling me to run the function, how I have tried in second attempt.

Comment: It's fetched only once (you can check it under your browser inspector Network Tab), but console.log is being called on every render. You will see console.log only once, if you put it inside your fetchInfo function, after `setBookData(data.data)`

Comment: So why is console.log() is rendered continuously. Is there any way to stop this happening. As I want to pass this data for some other purpose but since it is rendering again and again it is causing issue.

Comment: Any idea on why is it rendering continuously?

Answer (score 1):

Recreated your use case with a dummy `API`, I don't see this problem with `fetch`. The difference is that I used a function in `setBookData`.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React

const App = () => {
  const [bookData, setBookData] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    function fetchInfo() {
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(arr => {
          setBookData(() => {
            return arr.map(({title}) => title)
          })
        })
    }
    fetchInfo()
  }, [])

  console.log('this is bookdata', bookData)

  return (
    <div>
      {
        bookData.map((book, i) => {
          return `${i + 1}. ${book}`
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```